# A single language to learn to develop desktop and mobile phone applications?

Tags: programming-languages, cross-platform

Is there a language that is capable of developing apps to cross platform OSs (win,*nix) and mobile apps (IOS, android) ..
I'm a pro web developer but want to explore more environment to deploy my code into...

Python ? Ruby ?

Comment: HTML5.  Oh, wait.  You meant ***Programming Language,*** didn't you?  In any case, HTML5 will render on almost any modern computing device, and you can make the back end anything you want.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross-platform+mobile+programming

Comment: Any Turing complete language is capable of it.

Comment: For native apps, C++ may be the best choice since you can now develop in C++ on both iOS and Android. The problem you will have however is getting a cross platform UI library, of which there are some around, like [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade/supported-platforms). This blog post here might help as well: http://www.dodgycoder.net/2012/01/modern-cross-platform-development.html

Answer (score 4):

> A single language to learn to develop desktop and mobile phone applications?

The answer is **HTML5/Javascript**, because of:

- [PhoneGap's](http://phonegap.com/) ability to support 7 platforms.
- [Node.js/Topcube's](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/04/build-desktop-apps-with-nodejs.php) ability to let you develop a desktop application.

Comment: I could be alone in this sentiment, but PhoneGap seems to provide the lowest common denominator experience on all platforms. I get bummed out when I hear about people using it. Each platform has a very specific UI paradigm. A *good* app imho is one written natively. Towards that end, HTML5/Javascript is a great underlying tech to go learn, considering the growing opportunity with Windows 8 and future versions of Windows Phone rumored to support the same metro apps.

Comment: @PaulHazen: Two points: 1. Let's assume I buy your "lowest common denominator" argument. PhoneGap still lets you write an app for multiple platforms and gives you the ability to smooth out the rough edges with native programming wherever you see fit. 2. Your point of disagreement isn't applicable to the OP's question, and therefore, you just gave me an undeserved -1.

Comment: I think your answer is primarily wrong because you say that the answer is HTML5/Javascript *because* of PhoneGap. PhoneGap is not a good reason for why HTML5/JavaScript is a good choice. Additionally your response only covers Mobile, whereas the OP's question includes Windows and \*nix. Furthermore you don't specifically address how HTML5/JavaScript is a great solution for those platforms (not saying it *isn't* just saying your response doesn't make it clear).

Comment: We might just have a philosophical disagreement here. The OP is looking to learn how to learn new languages to target more platforms. There are plenty of languages that do that just fine without an additional middle layer. Maybe I'm a being a snobbish purist, but I think that there are far better options (such as the aforementioned python and java) that don't require the OP to learn a framework in addition to a language.

Comment: @PaulHazen, It looks that you missed second point in the list - it's about desktops. I'm quite good in C++, C# and JS, though not in python. And my choice is HTML5/JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn **python** in that case, because **python** is used in wide number of areas like **desktop applications**, **game scripting**, **android apps**, **web frameworks**.

top companies using python:

- Google
- youtube
- Facebook
- Dropbox
- Quora

and many more... the list is huge

Comment: Where can you use Python in iOS?

Comment: @SystemDown I only mentioned Android here, because apple uses objective-C for iPhone apps, and for MacOSX applications different python libraries are available which allows you to create cross-platform desktop applications.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a historical reason Microsoft does not use python, or were there other reasons you did not include them in your list?

Comment: @PaulHazen I've no idea about why they don't use python.
But for .NET developers there's ironPython, an open source implementation of python on which you can directly use .NET Api

Comment: Interesting. In RE:ironPython... gross.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - True about iOS and Android, I was just pointing it out because the OP specifically mentioned iOS in his question.

Comment: @PaulHazen - Microsoft originally created IronPython and IronRuby in-house (I went to school with the program manager of that group), but they shunted those projects out to the community. IronPython is a decent tie-in with the .NET framework, whereas IronRuby looks pretty stagnant. However, Microsoft has their own official family of languages, with C# being the favorite son, and also a heavy focus on C++. For scripting purposes, they're pushing Powershell, but I just assume the community didn't really take up the Iron languages enough, and they already had their own stuff instead of python.

Comment: Gooot it. That's actually interesting. I realized that my remark "gross" was out of place. My original interpretation of @AshwiniChaudhary's comment was that ironPython was a language converter that allowed developers to write code in their favorite flavor of .NET, and have it compile to executable Python. "Gross" was in reaction to my philosophical disagreement with language converters of *that* nature. Clearly I misunderstood the intent of iron python, entirely my fault because after re-reading the comment about it, it's perfectly clear. Thanks for the background/history!

Comment: [IronPython isn't Python](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IPy1.0.xCPyDifferences&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=ironpython) in some very important ways, some that will never be corrected.

Answer (score 3):

C++, C and any other portable native language (that can talk to C) meet your needs. You'll always have a platform-specific part in you app that you'll have to change for each platform (if you don't use an engine that does the work for you) but the application itself can be written independently.

Comment: Unless of course if you use a C++ based cross platform library like [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade/supported-platforms).

Answer (score 3):

C#.

It works on Windows (either with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) or regular .NET framework), on Linux and Mac (with Mono).

[Xamarin Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/) can be used to build apps for Android, iOS, and Windows Phone 7, though there are specific UI bits that are unique to each platform.

[Playstation Suite SDK](http://www.playstation.com/pss/index_e.html) currently only supports the use of C# (and is backed by Mono), and can be used to build apps/games for the Playstation Vita and Playstation-certified devices (currently only a handful of Sony-made Android phones and tablets).

[Unity Game Engine](http://unity3d.com/) can be used to build games for web browsers (with special plugin), iOS devices, Android devices, and if you have lots and lots of money and credentials, for consoles as well.

And some apps that are written with C#:

- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) - Desktop IDE for writing C# in
- [Tumbledrop](http://tumbledrop.com/) - iOS game written with Unity engine

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Java](http://www.java.com). [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) is made using Java and it runs on the desktop, and I'm sure you've heard of [Android](http://www.android.com) already for mobile devices. Java is used everywhere and is definitely cross-platform.

Comment: Java is not used on iOS, it is pretty much never will as VMs are specifically forbidden.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: It's a shame that this is the case.

Comment: javascript **is** used on iOS, and GWT can compile java to javascript...